# How to write to different region of same file by multi-thread in Qt under cross-platform?

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, qt, cross-platform

I need a cross-platform solution for multi-thread to write to a same file **concurrently**, at least Windows and Mac OS X. Different thread write to different file region.

The file is a little large. May be several GB or several hundred MB. So MMF doesn't fit right.

QFile is a cross-platform overlap. I have searched the QFile document, there isn't a share write option.

Under Windows, this can be done by CreateFile using FILE_SHARE_WRITE option. What about Mac OS X?

Does Qt support this or I should do my own encapsulation? How to do this under Mac OS X?

Comment: I wonder what the advantage of concurrent writing over synchronized writing would be, as this is hardly a CPU-bound problem and on some (lower) level, writing would have to be synchronized anyway.

Comment: Considering performance, I want to use non-blocking IO and ask all threads to write to a single file without thinking about locking. I will check the bottleneck CPU/IO.

Comment: @Frank Osterfeld After doing some research, [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/parallelcppnative/thread/042c3ef8-742d-4eda-9c74-018516d86b8c) makes me clear a lot. As you say, the bottleneck is IO, concurrent write can not help.

Comment: I wonder if memory-mapped files would help you with your task. I don't know if there is a cross-platform solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `QFile` with a `QReadWriteLock` ([documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qreadwritelock.html)).

Comment: Maybe my question isn't clear, I mean concurrent writing. I will update my question. Thank you all the same.

Comment: Do you mean multi-process writing? `FILE_SHARE_WRITE` only enables other processes to open the file, it does not handle actual concurrent writes. How would you ensure that the file is valid if multiple threads/processes write to the file concurrently? The order of the bytes would be random.

Comment: In my situation, there is one single process. Different thread write to different region, so the file will be valid.

Comment: Using `OVERLAPPED` structure can do asynchronous IO on OS layer. But as Frank said, there would be no benefit on performance. So your way would be enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X, there's no barrier to multiple processes or threads opening a file and writing within it, unless those processes or threads specifically opt into a cooperative locking scheme. Such opt-in cooperative locking schemes are called "advisory locking". For example, [`flock()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/flock.2.html) for locking whole files and [fcntl()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/fcntl.2.html) for byte-range locking.

Depending on how `QFile` is implemented, it may allow multi-thread writing just fine as-is. It would have to take special steps to disallow it.

Of course, if the threads or processes don't coordinate through some means, then they run the risk of overwriting and corrupting each other's data.